# How much information is missing?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, recreational-mathematics, fractions

If we know the value of $\frac{(a-b)}{(c-d)}$, can we calculate the value of $\frac{(a-d)}{(c-b)}$
That is : Let $\frac{(a-b)}{(c-d)}=k$ , can we calculate $\frac{(a-d)}{(c-b)}$ in terms of $k$
And *if not*, how can we show mathematically that it is not possible?, and that there is some information missing, is there a way to know how much information is missing?

Comment: It looks implausible doesn't it? So try to find two sets of $a,b,c,d$ with the same $k$ but different values of $\frac{a-d}{c-b}$.

Comment: To show it is not possible: find two sets of values $\{a,b,c,d\}$ such that $\frac{(a-b)}{(c-d)}$ is the same for them , but $\frac{(a-d)}{(c-b)}$ is different.